# Alternative way to create a promise with q

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I know how to create a promise in Kris Kowal's **q** with `var defer = Q.defer();`, calling `defer.resolve();` and/or `defer.reject()` and return `defer.promise`. But reading the [docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference), it seem's there is an alternative way to create a promise...

From the docs:

> **Q.Promise(resolver)**
>
> Synchronously calls `resolver(resolve, reject, notify)` and
>   returns a promise whose state is controlled by the functions passed to
>   resolver. This is an alternative promise-creation API that has the
>   same power as the deferred concept, but without introducing another
>   conceptual entity.
>
> If resolver throws an exception, the returned promise will be rejected
>   with that thrown exception as the rejection reason.

This is, what I've tried:

```
function () {
    return Q.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       (...do something...)
       resolve(5); // or: reject(error);
    });
}
```

But this doesn't work as expected!
**Can someone give an example, how to use `Q.Promise`?**

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for downvoting! I asked for an **usage example**, therefore a simple *"you use it in a correct way"* is more helpful! Btw: it fails silently and yes, I attached an error handler!

The reason, why the function is unnamed, is that I use it together with `map` and `reduce` to create a delayed chain of promises, but it seems, the **resolver** functions are never called... Therefore I asked for a (again) **usage example**...

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? What error do you get? What version of Q are you using?

Comment: "this doesn't work as expected". Are we meant to guess what's going wrong for you?

Comment: You did not name your function, your JS syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your 2 examples, I'm guessing you are doing this:

```
var q = require('q');
```

Therefore `Q.Promise` won't work, but rather `q.Promise` will.

Comment: The doc suggests ```var Q = require('q')``` and ```Q.Promise()```. In my code I use a lowercase **q** and ```q.Promise()```. But such errors are not really reasons to ask on SO...